# vue3 & jsx, how to get the parameters obtained by writing and obtaining slot

Tags: vue.js, jsx

vue3 & jsx, how to get the parameters obtained by writing and obtaining slot
code...

```
// parent.jsx
//...
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      this.$slots.cell({
         msg: 'parent'
      })
    <div>

  )
}
//...
```

```
// children.jsx
//...
setup(props){
  return <div>{ props.msg }</div>
}
//...
```

```
//use.jsx
//...
render() {
  return (
    <parent>
    // How to use the slot and get the passed parameters?
    <parent>

  )
}
//...
```

Looks like this[How to use template scope in vue jsx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702591/how-to-use-template-scope-in-vue-jsx).

Answer (score 0):

It's all here in the readme https://github.com/vuejs/jsx-next/#slot

use v-slots